# Pick random Place nearby using Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm currently looking at the Mapbox [Places Plugin for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/#install-the-places-plugin) and there doesn't seem to be functionality to choose a random Point-of-interest nearby (such as a restaurant, cafe, shop etc).

I want to insert a coordinate (Lat/Lng) into a Mapbox API and return with a random Place location (place name and place coordinates) within a certain radius.

Is this possible?

[I believe Point of interest category coverage](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#point-of-interest-category-coverage) could be what I'm after however I'm not sure how to use it in an Android context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's not complicated to do. First you need to start with point, around which to find places (bunch of parameters, like radius or limit of places) and simple request below.

```
# A basic reverse geocoding request
# Retrieve places near a specific location

# curl it's library for request on Mac and Linux
$ curl "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

2) As you can see above, there is no implementation for Android, to do within MapBox SDK. However, it's not a problem to just plan in request into your HTTP library in an application, like `OkHttp`.

In response you could receive next results, depends on your search param. Next step it's just serialize it from Json to DTO. Again using `OkHttp` library you can do it on flight.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "query": [
        "825",
        "s",
        "milwaukee",
        "ave",
        "deerfield",
        "il",
        "60015"
    ],
    "features": [{
            "id": "address.4356035406756260",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 1,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "Milwaukee Ave",
            "place_name": "825 Milwaukee Ave, Deerfield, Illinois 60015, United States",
            "matching_text": "South Milwaukee Avenue",
            "matching_place_name": "825 South Milwaukee Avenue, Deerfield, Illinois 60015, United States",
            "center": [
                -87.921434,
                42.166602
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -87.921434,
                    42.166602
                ],
                "interpolated": true,
                "omitted": true
            },
            "address": "825",
            "context": [{
                    "id": "neighborhood.287187",
                    "text": "Lake Cook Road"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.13903677306297990",
                    "text": "60015"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.5958304312090910",
                    "wikidata": "Q287895",
                    "text": "Deerfield"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.3290978600358810",
                    "short_code": "US-IL",
                    "wikidata": "Q1204",
                    "text": "Illinois"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.7464624790403620",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.5,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "Milwaukee Ave",
            "place_name": "825 Milwaukee Ave, Wheeling, Illinois 60090, United States",
            "matching_text": "South Milwaukee Avenue",
            "matching_place_name": "825 South Milwaukee Avenue, Wheeling, Illinois 60090, United States",
            "center": [
                -87.910299,
                42.144504
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -87.910299,
                    42.144504
                ],
                "interpolated": true
            },
            "address": "825",
            "context": [{
                    "id": "neighborhood.287187",
                    "text": "Lake Cook Road"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9418633295906190",
                    "text": "60090"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9902190947082220",
                    "wikidata": "Q935043",
                    "text": "Wheeling"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.3290978600358810",
                    "short_code": "US-IL",
                    "wikidata": "Q1204",
                    "text": "Illinois"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.6472754353404224",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.5,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "Milwaukee Avenue",
            "place_name": "825 Milwaukee Avenue, Glenview, Illinois 60025, United States",
            "matching_text": "South Milwaukee Avenue",
            "matching_place_name": "825 South Milwaukee Avenue, Glenview, Illinois 60025, United States",
            "center": [
                -87.852677,
                42.071152
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -87.852677,
                    42.071152
                ]
            },
            "address": "825",
            "context": [{
                    "id": "neighborhood.275266",
                    "text": "Northfield Woods"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.3787740186211610",
                    "text": "60025"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.10211845459386970",
                    "wikidata": null,
                    "text": "Glenview"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.3290978600358810",
                    "short_code": "US-IL",
                    "wikidata": "Q1204",
                    "text": "Illinois"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.1225436500189372",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.5,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "Milwaukee Ave",
            "place_name": "825 Milwaukee Ave, Buffalo Grove, Illinois 60089, United States",
            "matching_text": "South Milwaukee Avenue",
            "matching_place_name": "825 South Milwaukee Avenue, Buffalo Grove, Illinois 60089, United States",
            "center": [
                -87.917484,
                42.158084
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -87.917484,
                    42.158084
                ],
                "interpolated": true
            },
            "address": "825",
            "context": [{
                    "id": "neighborhood.287187",
                    "text": "Lake Cook Road"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.11727721238210580",
                    "text": "60089"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.8589721255665070",
                    "wikidata": "Q967086",
                    "text": "Buffalo Grove"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.3290978600358810",
                    "short_code": "US-IL",
                    "wikidata": "Q1204",
                    "text": "Illinois"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "address.240107872738130",
            "type": "Feature",
            "place_type": [
                "address"
            ],
            "relevance": 0.5,
            "properties": {},
            "text": "Milwaukee Avenue",
            "place_name": "825 Milwaukee Avenue, Wheeling, Illinois 60090, United States",
            "matching_text": "South Milwaukee Avenue",
            "matching_place_name": "825 South Milwaukee Avenue, Wheeling, Illinois 60090, United States",
            "center": [
                -87.898319,
                42.126289
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -87.898319,
                    42.126289
                ],
                "interpolated": true,
                "omitted": true
            },
            "address": "825",
            "context": [{
                    "id": "neighborhood.287189",
                    "text": "Milwaukee Avenue"
                },
                {
                    "id": "postcode.9418633295906190",
                    "text": "60090"
                },
                {
                    "id": "place.9902190947082220",
                    "wikidata": "Q935043",
                    "text": "Wheeling"
                },
                {
                    "id": "region.3290978600358810",
                    "short_code": "US-IL",
                    "wikidata": "Q1204",
                    "text": "Illinois"
                },
                {
                    "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                    "short_code": "us",
                    "wikidata": "Q30",
                    "text": "United States"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "attribution": "NOTICE: © 2018 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
}
```

3) Finally this data should be serialized into `Collection` of Objects. Where you can simply take random place from the result.

```
public static Item getRandomChestItem(List<Item> items) {
    return items.get(new Random().nextInt(items.size()));
}
```

---

**PS.** Would be nice receive this single item from initial request. But there is no option inside MapBox. It's meaningless from their respective, to use Map for random places. You could try to set options on request with limit only 1 place. But this place might not be random, because of library suggestion.

Comment: Thanks this is easier than I thought. I generate the reverse geocode json with `"https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${currentLocation.longitude},${currentLocation.latitude}.json?types=poi&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"` and that returns a list of POIs However there is no parameter to set a radius: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding - not sure if there's anything that can be done about that.

Comment: use `bbox` to limit the results to a rectangle, a circle is indeed not supported.

Comment: @Zorgan Sorry, didn't have time to check because of work. Need to check something like zoom, size. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Mapbox Tilequery API to set the radius and then eventually get a random point.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/tilequery/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/tilequery/

Use https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/ to play with the Mapbox Tilequery API. For example, https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/tilequery/-93.1393,44.946.json?limit=50&radius=1000&geometry=point&dedupe=true&access_token= PASTE_YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN_HERE.

*Make sure you request `point` geometries only*. This is done via `.geometry("point")` with the Mapbox Java SDK wrapper around the Tilequery API.

The API repsonse gives you a `FeatureCollection` of `Feature` objects. Then pick a random `Feature` and use its coordinates:

```
Point randomPoint = (Point) apiResponseFeatureList.get(new Random().nextInt(apiResponseFeatureList.size())).geometry();

if (randomPoint != null) {
  randomPoint.latitude();
  randomPoint.longitude();
}
```